# Is temporarily overwriting $wp_query a bad idea?

Tags: wp-query, query

I am in the process of rewriting a lot of my code and restructuring a lot of my theme files to use template parts (i.e. using `get_template_part()`). I've come upon a situation where I want to use the same template parts whether I'm using the main query or a secondary custom query (using `WP_Query`). The template parts also use core functions that rely on the main query (such as conditionals).

I can get around the problem by overwriting the main query (or overwriting the `$wp_query` global which holds the main query, the main query still exists) with my custom query and resetting the main query once I'm done. This also means I can use the same loop for the main query and my custom queries. For example:

```
// Query
if ( $i_need_a_custom_query ) {
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($custom_query_args);
}

// The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // Do some loop stuff
    // and call some functions that rely on the main query

// End the loop
endwhile; endif;

// I'm done so reset the query
wp_reset_query();
```

This works. No problem at all, but it seems a bit of a hack to me. So my question is:

- Am I right to be weary of overwriting the main query like this?
- Are there any side effects I'm missing?
- And am I correct in assuming that calling `wp_reset_query()` isn't costly (i.e. it isn't actually re-running the query but simply resetting the globals which are still around somewhere)?

Edit to clarify:

I am only using the custom queries in question as secondary queries, that's the whole point of the question. I want to use the same template wether I am using a custom *secondary* query or using the main query. I understand that what I am doing is essentially the same as using `query_posts()`, which is a bad idea. As far as I'm aware and broadly speaking, the 2 drawbacks to using `query_posts()` are 1. Performance, which isn't an issue because I am only doing this when running a secondary custom query anyway and 2. Unintended consequences from changing the global $wp_query, which is exactly what I *do* want to happen (and as I said is actually working perfectly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I agree with Howdy_McGee that one should avoid overwriting the main query unless absolutely necessary - more often than not, modifying the main query with something like a `'pre_get_posts'` hook is a better solution to such scenarios.

Manually overwriting the global `$wp_query` can cause all sorts of unintended behaviors if you are not exceedingly careful, including breaking pagination, among other things. It is, in essence, an even more simplistic equivalent to the often criticized `query_posts()` function, which [the WordPress Code Reference notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/):

> This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant options for modifying the main query such as via the ‘pre_get_posts’ action within WP_Query.

In this instance however, where you require either:

- Simultaneous access to both the main query as well as a secondary query for their distinct content and/or [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
- A generic implementation in something like a reusable template part that can be applied to either the main query or any custom query

then one solution is to store the "contextual" `WP_Query` instance in a local variable, and invoke `WP_Query`'s conditional methods on that variable instead of using  their globally-available conditional tag function counterparts (which always explicitly reference the main query, `global $wp_query`).

For instance, if you wanted your "contextual query variable" to refer to a custom secondary query in single and archive templates for your custom post type, `my-custom-post-type`, but refer to the main query in every other case, you could do the following:

**Theme's `functions.php` file, or a plugin file:**

```
function wpse_232115_get_contextual_query() {
  global $wp_query;
  static $contextual_query;

  // A convenient means to check numerous conditionals without a bunch of '||' operations,
  // i.e "if( $i_need_a_custom_query )"
  if( in_array( true,
    [
      is_singular( 'my-custom-post-type' ),
      is_post_type_archive( 'my-custom-post-type' )
    ]
  ) ) {
    // Create the contextual query instance, if it doesn't yet exist
    if( ! isset( $contextual_query ) ) {
      $query_args = [
        //...
      ];

      $contextual_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    }

    return $contextual_query;
  }

  return $wp_query;
}
```

**"Generic" template-part files:**

```
$query = wpse_232115_get_contextual_query();

// Contextual Query loop (loops through your custom query when 'my-custom-post-type's
// are being displayed, the main $wp_query otherwise.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  // Tags dependent on The Loop will refer to the contextual query if The Loop
  // was set up with the "$query->" prefix, as above. Without it, they always
  // refer to the main query.
  the_title();

  // The global conditional tags always refer to the main query
  if( is_singular() ) {
    //... Do stuff is the main query result is_singular();
  }

  // Conditional methods on the $query object reference describe either
  // the main query, or a custom query depending on the context.
  if( $query->is_archive() ) {
    //... Do stuff if the $query query result is an archive
  }
// End the loop
endwhile; endif;
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it's how I would think to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you should be using `get_template_part()` for markup. Let's say you have a Custom Template and the Blog which uses the same `get_template_part()`. You would call the template_part *in* the loop instead of calling The Loop in the part. For example:

**Your Custom Template**

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $custom_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( $path );
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

**Your Blog File**

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) { 
        the_post();
        get_template_part( $path );
    }
}
```

This will give both your custom template and your Blog File access to variables like `the_title()` and `the_permamlink()` without necessarily having to overwrite the main query. In the end, the above will give you more flexibility.

---

Overwriting the Main Query is *almost* always a bad idea and will become a headache later. The `wp_reset_query()` function isn't the biggest overhead but it still does more than really necessary when dealing with secondary queries. If we look at the [function itself](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) it pretty much resets a few more globals and calls the `wp_reset_postdata()` function which we could just call ourselves instead.

Comment: That is how I have always used template parts but a setup like I have now is saving a lot of duplicated code, it means I can reuse the whole query and surrounding template (my example code is a very stripped back example, there is actually a lot of code outside the loop) rather than just the in-loop markup.

Comment: and although I can use functions that rely on the global $post I still can't use for example conditionals that rely on the global $wp_query

Comment: @Cai the global conditionals are little more than wrappers that invoke `WP_Query` methods on the global `$wp_query` instance. So use the proper instance methods instead of the global functions - i.e. start with `$query = ( $i_need_a_custom_query ) ? new WP_Query( $custom_query_args ) : $wp_query;`. Thereafter, `is_singular()` will refer to the main query (as per usual), and `$query->is_singular()` will refer to either the custom query or the main query, depending on the context.

Comment: @bosco that's exactly what I ended up doing. Instead of overwriting `$wp-query` I use my own var which will either reference my custom query or the main query depending on the context. I was going to write my own answer but if you want to write that as an answer I can accept that :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is exactly to a T what `query_posts` does, and it really is a bad idea. To prove my point, here is the sorce code for [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)

```
function query_posts($query) {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
    return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($query);
}
```

Remember, `$GLOBALS['wp_query'] === $wp_query`. Now, look at your code, and you'll find it is the same.

There are more than enough writing about just how bad `query_posts` is, so take your time and work throught them.

There is never a valid reason to replace the main query on any page. Replacing the main query will **ALWAYS** lead to some issue, it might not be visible immediatly, but you'll definitely see the effect of it.

You'll also have to remember, if you are after SEO and performance, then the really bad news is that you definitely are doing it wrong then. The main query always runs normally on any page load, ie, it will query the db and return the relevant posts for the page. Simply removing the loop does **NOT** stop the main query. If you replace the loop with a custom one, as in your example, you are again querying the db, which means you are doing twice as much queries and also slowing the page down due to that. This negatively affect SEO, so there is something for you to think about.

To conclude, if you need something else from the main query, **ALWAYS** use `pre_get_posts` to alter it. This way you are not running any extra queries or breaking globals

Comment: None of my custom queries are to replace the main query, they are all secondary. The aim is to able to use the same template for example in archive.php and as a secondary query on a static front page.

Comment: Regardless of how I do this, the same number of queries are going to be run so that isn't an issue at all. Affecting the behaviour of thing that rely on $wp-query is exactly why I do want to do this so I'm still not sure why this is such a bad idea?

Comment: And the whole reason for this question is that I think it *is* a bad idea... I just can't see any practical reason why (I'm not sure how SEO comes in to it?)

Comment: @Cai `WP_Query` invokes considerably sizable database queries. Sizable database queries = longer page loads = lower SEO rankings. Thus, it is virtually always desirable to use a single main query where possible. People often seek to use `query_posts()` with custom arguments to circumvent the main query and populate their page, resulting in an unnecessary `WP_Query` and pointlessly taxing page load-times - this is why using `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query instead of letting it run then overwriting it is oft asserted (albeit your use-case is somewhat different as you want both queries)

Comment: @Cai I get where you're coming from with the question about *why*, though. For the most part it sounds like `query_posts()` should be acceptable if used responsibly. I think the most valid argument is that replacing the main-query mid-script can cause all sorts of bizarre and poorly-documented behaviors, like breaking pagination. It's difficult to use the function responsibly when you need to know every theme, plugin, and core function that's relying on the consistency of the main query in order to do so.